# Setting up DHCP for Virtualbox VMs

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have my own physical server, on which I run Ubuntu 16.04.2 Server OS as well as other virtual machines (using Virtual Box 5.1.22). I have 4 physical network cards which I want to bundle to each specific VM.

For instance, I want one VM to directly use one card, another VM (e.g. Windows 10) to use another network card.

The problem is that I cannot see my network cards via virtual machines. I tried both setting up **host-only** and **bridged** networks for VM, but it did not work - I still do not see any network present.

I used this command:

VBoxManage modifyvm "my-ubuntu-server-vm" --memory 4096 --acpi on --boot1 dvd --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 one-of-mynetwork-card-names-here

But it did not help. On VM, I only see loopback and some other network interface (used ip a to check network interfaces).

I guess the problem is with DHCP as when I did installation, it could not configure DHCP automatically.

Could you please suggest me what to do next? Should I somehow change the DHCP configurations? If yes, then how and where, on host or guest?

Thank you!